# How to insert formula with specific characters using VBA script correctly

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I would like to insert this formula

> =IF(L257>28;">28";IF(AND(L257<=28;L257>21);"≤28";IF(AND(L257<=21;L257>14);"≤21";IF(AND(L257<=14;L257>7);"≤14";IF(L257<=7;"≤7";"error")))))

with excel vba to a specific cell, if I'm recording it then the code is not running at all, I mean I will receive an error code, or if I try to change these signs ≤ to this <= it is only showing the "=" mark and the number as the result but not showing this particular "<"  sign. Can you help me how should I put this into a VBA code or what should be the solution?

It is recording something like this

```
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]>28,"">28"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=28,RC[-1]>21),""=28"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=21,RC[-1]>14),""=21"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=14,RC[-1]>7),""=14"",IF(RC[-1]<=7,""=7"",""error"")))))"
Range("M3").Select
```

Comment: First thing to do is to replace all `;` with `,`. It is different in VBA and in Excel

Comment: Seems to be working for me, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you also include a sample of the output you expect vs the output you're actually getting? i.e. expecting `string value: <=7` getting  `string value: =7` (guesses from your post, not sure if interpreting correctly). You also mentioned sometimes getting an error code: which one? What does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Unicode character in your formula as below, this will use the Greater or Equal symbol from your desired formula and display it correctly:

> Unicode Character 8804 = ChrW(8804) = **≤**

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>28,"">28"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=28,RC[-1]>21),""" & ChrW(8804) & "28"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=21,RC[-1]>14),""" & ChrW(8804) & "21"",IF(AND(RC[-1]<=14,RC[-1]>7),""" & ChrW(8804) & "14"",IF(RC[-1]<=7,""" & ChrW(8804) & "7"",""error"")))))"
```